# Adding Directory to Stack Then Counting the Directory's Contents

Tags: java, stack

I have a stack to which I am trying to add a directory (a directory that contains two (2) child .txt files - just to keep things simple, for now):

```
public static int fileCount(File directory)
{
    Stack<File> fileStack = new Stack<File>();
    fileStack.push(directory);
}
```

That part, obviously, is simple; however, the following part is where I am stuck. I know how - in theory, at least - to traverse that directory so that I can "figure out" how many files are in it (in other words, to reach its children). Here is my attempt, so far (and Stacks appear pretty simpe, so I must be missing something, larger):

```
// Same method, with the meaningful "guts" added:
public static int fileCount(File directory)
{
    Stack<File> fileStack = new Stack<File>();
    filestack.push(directory); 

    int totalFiles = 0;

    while(!fileStack.isEmpty()
    {
        try
        {
            File poppedElement = (File)fileStack.pop(); // Here's where I think my problem is

            if (poppedElement.isFile())
            {
                totalSize++;
            }
            else
            {
                fileStack.push(fileStack.peek());
            }
        }
        catch(EmptyStackException emptyStackException)
        {
             emptyStackException.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return totalFiles;
}
```

I think the first portion of my problem is that I `.pop()` the element before anything happens to it (which would also mean that the EmptyStackException is returned). Any guidance at this juncture is appreciated.

The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867821/chow-to-use-stdstack-to-deal-with-the-file-directory-hierarchy) seems to be the way to go about it (which, although my solution is not recursive), feels to be the same way (though in a different language). Clearly, this is a breadth-first search (BFS) - an awesome article about which can be found, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32212/Introduction-to-Graph-with-Breadth-First-Search-BF). The trouble I am having is implementing a solution that is able to get the children of the popped, top element.

Comment: `BFS` problem. Get the object returned by `fileStack.pop()`, then add its `children` to the `fileStack` in your code

Comment: @zybjtu Exactly. In this case, how would you get to its children? That's my question.

Comment: `listFiles()` method? @Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Differences in the Correct Solution

The below is a `public static` method and therefore is a code fragment. The code is considerably different from that posted in the initial question in three (3) ways:

1. When the method is first called, an array of of `File` objects is instantiated and initialized to the content - the `File` objects - of the the specified path (here, a directory or folder).
2. The method iterates over each file element in array `File[] potentialDirectories`, pushing each element to `StackFile> fileStack`, regardless of its "folder" or "file" state. The *directory* is not pushed, the *directory's content* is pushed.
3. In the `while(condition)` loop, the `else` body has changed, considerably. The else condition is `true` if the element is not a file, i.e. a folder. If the element is a folder, `potentialDirectories` is re-initialized to contain the contents - the elements - of that folder: `potentialDirectories = poppedElement.listFiles()` and, again, each element is pushed to the stack.

The third difference is perhaps the most important in that this is the difference that enables the examination - the iteration over - the child elements by first getting them and second pushing them to the stack. If the element is not a file, we know it can contain other `File` objects and therefore can `listFile()` the not-file (folder) element, accessing each child.

#### The Code

```
public static int fileCount(File directory) throws NullPointerException
{
    Stack<File> fileStack = new Stack<File>();
    File[] potentialDirectories = directory.listFiles();

    for (File file: potentialDirectories)
    {
        fileStack.push(file);
    }

    int totalSize = 0;

    while (!fileStack.isEmpty())
    {   
        File poppedElement = (File)fileStack.pop();


        if(poppedElement.isFile())
        {
            totalSize++;
        }
        else
        {
            potentialDirectories = poppedElement.listFiles();

            for (File file: potentialDirectories)
            {
                fileStack.push(file);
            }
        }
    }

    return totalSize;
}
```